# How to manage JPATokenStore with Axon Server

Tags: axon

We’re using Axon Server community edition and Postgres for our projections and JPATokenStore on an AWS EKS cluster - kubernetes and helm:

When we upgrade our helm charts causing AxonServer and our Axonified Spring Boot application (pods) to restart, we end up in a state where event handlers are no longer firing. In remote debug we can see that the commands and EventSourcingHandlers are being invoked properly, but none of our EventHandlers are ever invoked.

We seem to have some success by manually dropping the TOKEN_ENTRY table in the Postgres database. We are speculating that by restarting the AxonServer but leaving the TokenStore untouched, we are probably breaking the EventProcessor. But then again, we’re not deleting the PV between AxonServer restarts, so it’s unclear.

What should we expect when restarting our service and AxonServer?
Should we be dropping TOKEN_ENTRY tables whenever the AxonServer restarts?
Should we only do that when the AxonServer volume (disk space) is cleaned?
What are the best practices here?

Answer (score 1):

I would at least try not to restart both server and applications simultaneously. But this is probably easier said than done.

When you restart the server, do you also persist the volumes, and, thus the events? If you do remove the events, you also need to remove the TOKEN_ENTRY table, as otherwise, it will start to read from a position in the stream that no longer exists. If you don't remove the events, I would expect the event processors to continue what they left before the restart.

Comment: thanks Gerard, yes depending on the state of the upgrade (this is mostly happening in our CICD processes) we sometimes need to restart the axonserver with a clean volume (clear out the eventstore) and other times simply restart - it was mainly best practice we were after. So are you saying: "A) Clean eventstore start => restart axonserver, clean volume + drop tables in postgres.. B) simple restart, no volume drop => NO database change" correct? is this documented anywhere? Is there anyway to get axon to truncate the token_entry table?

Comment: Not sure it's documented somewhere. In production you don't remove/reset the events. But indeed, do a 'full reset' you need to remove everything. So probably not just TOKEN_ENTRY. For example in projections you now have entities, but the events used to created the entities are no longer there.